# Reading Data from Application: conflicts with many users?

Tags: c#, .net

I notice this problem : if I store an object in application on .NET 3.5/C# as :

```
HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
if (ctx.Application["object"] == null)
    ctx.Application["object"] = new MyObject();

return (MyObject)ctx.Application["object"];
```

and many users try to get it and iterate it (with a foreach) I can get some troubles : the iteration sometimes will fails, miss some data, and return an incorrect result.

I read that there are many of these problem reading on application on .NET, but I don't know how resolve.

How can I fix this problem?

## EDIT

This crash on data like :

```
var Example = from MyCollection collection in MyObject.Collections
               select collection;
```

which is `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`.

Well, on the object `ctx.Application["object"]` there is some collections, and many of this (the ones who crash) are System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable. If userA iterate a collection (stored in MyObject) and meanwhile userB iterate the same collection, userA can miss some values from this collection, and userB can get duplicate values of that collection.

I can't say with precision how much and which values are miss/duplicate, since it's an elaboration problem. That's is what I mean with "return an incorrect result".

And no, I only read data, I don't change/edit/add anything to this collections during the read.

Comment: You should not share mutable objects across requests.

Comment: Are any of the threads manipulating / mutating / changing the values *inside* MyObject ?

Comment: I know, but many data is the same for all users. That's why I'd like to use them...

Comment: @Marc Gravell♦ : no they are/must be read-only (and In fact I only get data). The problem is when I cycle them on foreach, as I said. For every MyObject there is an iterator, and this crash...

Comment: make sure your object is readonly collection.

Comment: many of data that I cycle is IEnumerable, maybe that's sucks on foreach...?

Comment: @markbuzz saying it is IEnumerable doesn't tell us anything about repeatability - what is it **actually**? A list? Array? What?

Comment: there is various IEnumerable into the object. Some is an array, some is a list...

Comment: @markzzz there is no issue enumerating a list or array many many times in parallel, **as long as** the list/array is not changed.

Comment: Your edit is not valid c#, so it doesn't help us understand... Again: there is nothing inherently wrong with massive parallel iteration; whatever is going odd sounds specific to whatever *else* is going on, which we can't see... Perhaps you could clarify exactly what happens when it "return incorrect result@? And confirm:  are you, **at any point** adding/removing/changing values in the list? Which could be on a completely different request; it will still cause mayhem

Comment: check the updates! Hope this is more clear..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure how does **IEnumerable** handle multiple loopings at once but it seems, that it don't do it very well, as there is only one enumerator for everyone. Try [locking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) the object before looping, so every thread will wait untill another one will end the looping.

Comment: it is impossible to comment in te general case, but generally an enumerable item is either "once only" or "as much as you like" (as long as it isn't changed). There is no inherent problem that would usually affect an enumerable sequence **some** of the time

Answer (score 1):

Based on limited info, it **sounds** like a classic "mutating a shared object" problem. Te fix for this can be simple:

Option 1: never change the shared object. If you need to change it, make a **deep copy** (but with the changed values), then swap that for the stores value:

```
ctx.Application[key] = newValue;
```

In combination with this all readers must only fetch the object **once only** and must re-use this snapshot for the duration of their request, to avoid consistent state.

Option 2: perform complex synchronisation, with either exclusive locks or cooperative locks (such as reader/writer, useful if most access is readonly)

The first is simpler and recommended, but may have overheads if the data is fast changing or very large. The second is more complex and much harder to get right, but **done perfectly** can be lower overhead.

Comment: Not sure about your first solution! In fact I do that on Application. The problem is cycling an IEnumerable (inside the MyObject) with a for each : the iterator crash, and I don't know. Do You know how to resolve this?

Comment: @markzzz until you tell us that the underlying implementation of the enumerable is, how can we possibly answer? It is the underlying implementation that defines the behaviour